# Weird behavior in Google chrome (After submitting a form, it goes to the bottom of the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have template design. Everything works fine except when I submit a form. When the server responds (same page), it will go to the bottom of the page. It happens if the whole page is bigger than the screen's height.

- Example (if whole page is smaller than the screen's height):

  - Submit form, server responds with same page, then the page stays at the top.
- Example (if whole page is bigger than the screen's height):

  - Submit form, server responds with same page, then the page goes to the bottom.

I have disabled the javascript (removed the `<script>` tags). And it only happens in Chrome.

I have tested it in firefox and IE, and the page will stay at the top after submitting a form.

..........

Also, if I put an empty `<script> </script>` tag before the content, exactly like this. The page (in Chrome) will stay at the top. I'm assuming it has to be on how Chrome renders the page.

If there is no `<script>` tag, Chrome will aggressively render the page. And if there is a `<script>` tag somewhere in the content, it will render it slower or differently.

..........

Also, I'm using Symfony2 (a PHP framework), it happens every time when in `dev` mode. When I switch to `prod` mode (css and js get compiled and merged), it happens rarely.

I would normally say the problem is the CSS/HTML layout but in only happens in Chrome and if the page is served in a timely manner (fast), the problem disappears (the page stays at the top).

**My question is**: Is this a known issue? Can it be fixed relatively easy? Or should I just pray the page is loaded fast so the problem doesn't happen?

Chrome version: 38.0.2125.111 (64-bit)

If you need more details, I would be gladly to provide them. Thanks in advance

**Edit:** Server responds the same page both `dev` and `prod` mode. The difference is that in `prod` mode, it is optimized for a production environment. The CSS/JS get merged and compiled, making the page load faster.

Comment: Can I suggest that we use a better question title?

Comment: @Kolban Sure. What would you suggest? I googled it and I found nothing. Maybe I'm choosing the wrong words.

Comment: Sounds like the page jump behavior when you jump to an unknown anchor. Like, if you use `<a href="#"` and don't override the click handler, Chrome will jump to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Validate the HTML on your page.

Comment: I also thought it was a problem with an anchor. What do you mean override the click handler? I have removed all the scripts the template uses. Also, it only happens in `dev` mode (the same exact page). `dev` mode, since it's debugging, the page is loaded slower.

Comment: @iambriansreed Yes, I used http://validator.w3.org/ service to validate the HTML. There is no broken HTML tags, or tags that aren't allowed inside other tags. Please keep in mind that server serves the same page in both `dev` and `prod` mode, the difference is that `prod` mode is optimized for production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance anybody is experiencing this, this is my solution:

Make sure to  minify/uglify, compile/merge the CSS. Use aggressive cache. So Chrome doesn't render the page without the necessary CSS style.

Using `<script> </script>` tag somewhere in the content is a hack.

I would recommend to use jquery:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
```

The problem would only occur if after submitting the form, you don't redirect (form has errors). If there are form errors, you would probably show a message div alert, so with that script you would scroll/animate to that div element.